# How to create a nested dictionary from pandas mean() and std()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataset` with state names and some numeric data:

```
d = {'state' : pd.Series(['ALASKA','CALIFORNIA','TEXAS'], index=[0,1,2]),
     'numericdata' : pd.Series([342, 234,756], index=[0,1,2])}
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to go through each state and calculate the `mean()`, and `std()` and add it to a `dict` to retrieve later.

I would like my `dict` to look like this: `d = {'ALASKA':{'mean':1,'std':6}}`

My problem is that I've never used dictionaries in python and I'm not really sure how to create a dictionary within a dictionary. I'm open to any suggestions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can get you even more with `describe`

```
df.groupby('state')['numeric data'].describe().unstack().to_dict('index')

{'ALASKA': {'25%': 342.0,
  '50%': 342.0,
  '75%': 342.0,
  'count': 1.0,
  'max': 342.0,
  'mean': 342.0,
  'min': 342.0,
  'std': nan},
 'CALIFORNIA': {'25%': 234.0,
  '50%': 234.0,
  '75%': 234.0,
  'count': 1.0,
  'max': 234.0,
  'mean': 234.0,
  'min': 234.0,
  'std': nan},
 'TEXAS': {'25%': 756.0,
  '50%': 756.0,
  '75%': 756.0,
  'count': 1.0,
  'max': 756.0,
  'mean': 756.0,
  'min': 756.0,
  'std': nan}}
```

---

Keep it to just `mean` and `std`

***option 1***

```
df.groupby('state')['numeric data'].agg(['mean', 'std']).to_dict('index')

{'ALASKA': {'mean': 342.0, 'std': nan},
 'CALIFORNIA': {'mean': 234.0, 'std': nan},
 'TEXAS': {'mean': 756.0, 'std': nan}}
```

***option 2***

```
df.groupby('state')['numeric data'].describe().unstack()[['mean', 'std']].to_dict('index')

{'ALASKA': {'mean': 342.0, 'std': nan},
 'CALIFORNIA': {'mean': 234.0, 'std': nan},
 'TEXAS': {'mean': 756.0, 'std': nan}}
```

Comment: This is a way better answer than what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I will accept this answer as soon as the time is up.

Comment: what if `numericdata` was actually `numeric data`?